# "Cleverly" replace expression when simplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I want to simplify $5a\cdot x+5b\cdot y+6 c+c^2$, if possible, given that $e=a\cdot x+b\cdot y+c$.

I don't want to replace $c=e-a\cdot x-b\cdot y$. I want to replace it "cleverly".

So, a nice simplification result can be $5e+c+c^2$.

Is this possible? and how?

Comment: Use `PolynomialReduce`: `In[53]:= PolynomialReduce[5*a*x + 5*b*y + 6*c + c^2, 
  a*x + b*y + c - e, {x, y, a, b, c, d, e}][[2]]

Out[53]= c + c^2 + 5 e`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second argument of [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) can list known conditions, relationships, and assumptions:

```
FullSimplify[5 a x + 5 b y + 6 c + c^2, e == a x + b y + c]
(*    c + c^2 + 5 e    *)
```

Comment: I get the same result using `Simplify`, i.e., `Simplify[5 a*x + 5 b*y + 6 c + c^2, e == a*x + b*y + c]`

Answer (score 5):

Solve with elimination of ax or by or  both together at the same time.

```
Solve[{5 ax + 5 by + 6 c + c^2 == f, e == ax + by + c}, f, {ax}]

(*   {{f -> c + c^2 + 5 e}}   *)
```

Comment: Math representation is not so clear: $a x$ and $b y$ are not one variable but two: $a*x$

Comment: use `$a~x$` to put space $a ~x$

Comment: @Chameleon Even better would be to post your formulas as code, not (just) as TeX. Makes it easy for others to help you: easier to copy/paste, fewer misinterpretations.

Answer (score 3):

```
GroebnerBasis[{5*a*x + 5*b*y + 6*c + c^2, a*x + b*y + c - e}, {x, y, 
  a, b, c, d, e}]
```

> `{c + c^2 + 5 e, c - e + a x + b y}`

Comment: The answer depends on the ordering of the variables in the second argument of `GroebnerBasis`. For this method to work as requested, one would have to try all permutations of the variables and choose the minimal `LeafCount`: something like `MinimalBy[GroebnerBasis[{5*a*x + 5*b*y + 6*c + c^2, a*x + b*y + c - e}, #][[1]] & /@ Permutations[{x, y, a, b, c, d, e}], LeafCount] // DeleteDuplicates`.

Comment: @Roman thanks for pointing this out. If you want to make it a fully-fledged answer, I am happy to delete mine

Comment: @Roman The ordering used above is just fine for the task at hand. The problem is that this does not provide an indication of how the original polynomial transforms. Which is one reason I would instead advocate for using `PolynomialReduce`.